# Book which has a proof of NP-completness for Partition Problem

Tags: optimization

I need the name of a book which has a proof of NP-completness for Partition Problem.
I need to cite it in a my bachelor thesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Garey, Michael; Johnson, David (1979). Computers and Intractability; A Guide to the Theory of NP-Completeness. pp. 96–105